# Call to undefined method App\Post::withCount()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I can't find where is the problem. I have `posts` and `comments` table. In `comments`table i have added `foreign key` `post_id`. And now i want to get comments count same time when i get all posts.

Here is my `PostController`

```
public function show_api()
{
   return $this->withCount('comments')->get();
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class);
}
```

In `CommentController`

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: have you defined these relations in the controller ? and not in the model ?

Comment: yes just in controller

Comment: @MRustamzade you're also using `hasManyThrough` which will not work here.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin yes you right. I changed it to hasMany. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have defined these relations in the controller rather than model. 
You should define these relations in the respective models and then it should work.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you should use `hasMany` relationship:

```
class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Then this will work:

```
Post::withCount('comments')->get();
```